# Button link does not work on mobile display

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this template : http://technext.github.io/humanity/ 
in the Blog News section the Read more button does not work on mobile.the only difference is that in the html code i have add an tag

```
<a href="something.html"><div class="button-main bg-fio-point">read more</div></a>
```

moreover the image also does not work as a link too on a mobile phone..
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, make a coherent HTML. Turn the html like this:

```
 <div class="button-main bg-fio-point"><a href="something.html">read more</a></div>
```

Your code is for special cases and for expert layouters. You must to use the normal and valid code like this purpose.

Comment: Have you got events in this link ? Maybe you have an `event.preventDefault()` and with this, links don't work.

Comment: no event is connected. my code is almost identical with the one in the template..

Comment: Links `<a>` works in all devices without any code. If an `<a>` tag doesn't works, the most probably thing that happens is a `preventDefault()` or `stopPropagation()`

Comment: the only thing i found i this:
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  //Handles menu drop down
  $('.dropdown-menu').find('form').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        });
  });
</script>
but isnt this for another class?

Comment: That doesn't be related... I don't know what happens. Try to make a https://jsfiddle.net with the issue and I can help you. With the details in this post is impossible to see what happens.

Comment: i gave the link of the template in order to do inspect element because i could not post all the code.

Comment: MCVE = Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example. See more: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve You haven't got to post all code, only an example that reproduces the problem. In the template you attached there are no errors.

Comment: the problem is that i dont know the code that reproduce the problem. and in the template if you do inspect element and "make it mobile" from the option that inspect element gives you. there is the same problem

Comment: If you inspect that elements, you've got two layers above the content, so when you make click really you are making click in the layer, not in the button. You should make  `display:none` for responsive version to layers `.bx-wrapper`  and `.bx-wrapper + .clearfix`. I make it and now "Read more" boxes are clickable.

Comment: i am sorry i didnt understand tou. where should i put display:none?

Comment: `@media screen and (max-width: 786px) { .bx-wrapper, .bx-wrapper + .clearfix { display: none; } }`

Comment: i hope it doesnt affect anything else

Comment: In mobile version doesn't affect to nothing, it's because I add the mediaquery to resolutions less than 768px. If you feel something wrong modify it to 540px

Comment: Please, add an upvote to the answer ;) I'm growing reputation xD thank you!

Comment: i am sorry i cant because my reputation is under 15